# Would Magento handle multidomain e-shop with different skins but the same products?

Tags: multistore, multi-vendor, multishipping

Would Magento be able to provide system for

- few e-shops
- sharing the same products (the same info about products)
- but (maybe) different pricing for some of them
- different shipping based on the country where the warehouse is
- on the other hand I will start operating from one country so I will have one 1 warehouse. So I want to have one system that would track how many items are on stock.
- but the whole system would run on different domains like shop1.com, some_other_shop.com.au and the_best_shop_ever.net
- different type of account for 'normal' user and resellers with different pricing, bulk discounts etc.

Thank you for any direction ...

Answer (score 2):

Short answer to all your questions is Yes. Magento can do all that out of box. If you need to know HOW then you should ask more specific questions.

Good place to start learning about Magento features is Magento User Guide: http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide

Comment: I never had anything to do with Magento before so I am happy to know that the answers are Yes. Now I need to some reading. Could you point me out. Are there any examples, show cases etc?

Comment: You could start as did -- install latest version and get cracking. There's a user guide to help you one the way: http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide